# The relationship between Spearman coefficient and Pearson Coefficient

Tags: probability, statistics, nonparametric-statistics

The Spearman coefficient is defined as following:$r_s = 1- \frac{6\Sigma d^2}{n(n^2 -1)}=1$
and the Person Coefficient is given by $r_p=\frac{\sum ^n _{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\sqrt{\sum ^n _{i=1}(x_i - \bar{x})^2} \sqrt{\sum ^n _{i=1}(y_i - \bar{y})^2}}$.

My question is : If we know that $r_s=1$, can we conclude that $r_p\neq 0$?

Comment: Similar question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/598265/spearman-correlation-and-pearson-correlation

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What does $r_s = 1- \frac{6\Sigma d^2}{n(n^2 -1)}=1$ tell you about the $d$?

Comment: We can get $d=0$, but $d=0$ must imply $r_p\neq 0$?

Comment: If so then you have an answer to your question